# How can I copy JOIN-ed sql table?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts_copy * (SELECT 
        *
FROM 
        wp_posts
        JOIN wp_term_relationships
                ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE 
   wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = "48")
```

SQL database:

```
wp_posts => 
ID
post_author
post_date
post_date_gmt
post_content
post_title
post_excerpt
post_status
comment_status
ping_status
post_password
post_name
to_ping
pinged
post_modified
post_modified_gmt
post_content_filtered
post_parent
guid
menu_order
post_type 
post_mime_type
comment_count

wp_term_relationships =>
object_id
term_taxonomy_id
term_order
```

I would like to copy or export those wp_posts that are in that category what has got id 48. The selection is working, but I don't know how to copy them.  Well, how can I copy the selected data? It's from a WP database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy only columns from `wp_posts` you have to use `wp_posts.*` instead of `*` or name all columns you want to use

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts_copy
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts
JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id
WHERE wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = "48"
```